# using xargs in an alias to remove svn unversioned files interactively?

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm trying to create a bash alias to remove, interactively, all svn unversioned files.  I've gotten as far as

```
svn st | grep '^\?'| sed 's/^?       //'
```

to get a list of such files.  Piping into xargs -p rm just gives me a single prompt for all the files, e.g.

`rm fileA fileB fileC fileD ?...`

whereas I want to confirm each file individually.  On the command line, I can do

```
rm -i $(svn st | grep '^\?'| sed 's/^?       //')
```

to get the desired behavior, but it doesn't work when I stick it in an alias or function.

Comment: Why doesn't it work when you stick it in a function?

Comment: Also, rather than splitting the results on whitespace, you might want to split them *just* on newlines. Your current approaches will both misbehave if any of your filenames contain spaces.

Comment: It gives me the same result as when I use xargs, just a single prompt for all files.

Comment: Are you sure you used the new alias/function and not accidentally the old xargs one? Did it actually ask `rm: remove regular file: ...` and not `rm lol.c lol.hi ?`?

Comment: Whoa, you guys are right!  I was sure I'd re-sourced my alias file and my history suggests I did, but maybe there was some sync error and my emacs didn't save as quickly as I thought or something.

Thanks a lot.